# Jenkins unable to connect GIT repository: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)

Tags: git, jenkins

Hi my Jenkins instance is unable to connect to GIT repository although I googled a lot. Both Jenkins and GIT were installed on same CentOS server. This is the screenshot I got during pipeline set up:

[image]

I have done following:

1. Make sure .ssh directory of GIT is of mode 700;
2. Make sure .ssh/authorized_keys of GIT is of mode 600;
3. Added Jenkins public key to .ssh/authorized_keys of GIT;
4. Log in as Jenkins and execute 'git ls-remote -h :test.git HEAD' on command line - it will prompt for git password;
5. Added git username/password to Jenkins under Credentials

Comment: What is the result of an `ssh -v git@your.server`? Git uses internally ssh, so you could debug it.

Comment: On which machines did you perform steps 1 thru 3?

Comment: I executed steps 1 through 3 just on the same Centos Server.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica, I first logged into server using account jenkins then execute 'ssh -v git@my.server' then there is prompt asking for credentials of my private key: `code debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
Enter passphrase for key '/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa':` after I typed passphrase then I logged in as git

Comment: And did you install both jenkins and git under the same user? Are they running as the same user?

Comment: Oh, you have a passphrase on the ssh key - not sure how jenkins handles that

Comment: Probably your credentials in step 5 is not correctly set up. It should be the private key with a passphrase specified. Jenkins will not use the keys in `~/.ssh`.

Comment: @fredrik Jenkins is under user jenkins and GIT is under user git.

Comment: @fredrik you are right - problem is solved after I put private key in. Could you please post your answers in answers instead of comments so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins will not use the SSH Keys located on the master or slave that runs the job. So your setup with placing the keys in `~/.ssh` and having a username/password credential set up on on the master will not work.

Instead you should create a set of credentials using the [SSH Credential Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin), where you can also specify the passphrase for the private key. The jobs then need to use this credential to connect to the repository.